# How to select data from database with many filter options?

Tags: c#, sql, performance

I am creating C# winforms application, which connects to the Database.
Because I have a many records in database, I want to filter data on sql side (Filter must have many options without start/end date).

What is a best way to achive this?

I know I can use BindingSource for filtering, but I think It is not recomended, because in this case I must select all data from database.

p.s. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: WHY NOT YOU USE STORED PROCEDURE OR SIMPLE TEXT QUERY WITH WHERE CLAUSE?

Comment: Stored procedure will be too complex and simple text query is not the secure way.

Comment: @Vano is right about security. http://en.csharp-online.net/ASP.NET_Security_Hacks%E2%80%94Avoiding_SQL_Injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always prefer filtering data on database instead of bringing unwanted data to your application and filtering with code.

Eg

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable ";
```

In the string below you add a WHERE clause and pairs of column = value  or column = expression

```
 string query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE column1=somevalue AND column2 > somevalue AND ...";
```