# Sql Query Help, syntax error near =

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

why is this not working ?  It's something about the commandstring syntax near `=` but I can't seem to figure it out, the online examples seem exactly the same.
**Edit:** Activated In is a column.

examples from [How to select data from database with many filter options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620843/how-to-select-data-from-database-with-many-filter-options)

```
private void btnDist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Rep <> '#NA' AND Activated In = '#NA'";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, GetConnection());
    DataSet distDS = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(distDS);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = distDS.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the name of the column on your database is `Activated In` (with a space) then you need to use square brackets when referring to the object / column name in queries, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Rep <> '#NA' AND [Activated In] = '#NA'
```

This is because SQL treats spaces as a separator in the query language - square brackets are used to "escape" this (and other characters) in names.

Alternatively if the column is just called `Activated` then you don't need the `IN` bit - either test for equality or test to see if the value is in a given range, but don't do both.

```
-- Use this
SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Rep <> '#NA' AND Activated = '#NA'
-- Or this
SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Rep <> '#NA' AND Activated IN ('#NA', 'Some other value')
```

Comment: Which is why you should avoid using spaces or keywords in the table design inteh first place. If this is a new table not yet pushed to prod, I would immediately fix the fieldname.

Comment: @Kragen, thanks a lot for the answer man, Activated In is(was) a column name so the brackets fixed the problem. Wouldn't even know what the actual IN keyword is for

Answer (score 4):

change you query to There is no need of `IN` keyword

```
SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Rep <> '#NA' AND Activated = '#NA'"
```

`IN` - used when you want to filter out data from the list or subquery is there.

Answer (score 2):

The `In` keyword is used as follows:

```
...AND Activated IN ('#NA')
...AND Activated IN ('#NA', 'other filter value', 'more filter values')
```

Answer (score 1):

`Activated In = '#NA'"`

This needs to be `Activated In ('#NA')"` or `Activated = '#NA'"`.
The `In` operator in SQL is reserved.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `=` after `In`

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Rep <> '#NA' AND Activated In ('#NA')";
```

You might also want to use `=` instead of `In` since you are only specifying one item.

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Rep <> '#NA' AND Activated = '#NA'";
```

If `Activated In` is a column, then use:

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Rep <> '#NA' AND [Activated In] = '#NA'";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Activated In** is a column ? then it should have been  **ActivatedIn** or **[Activated In]**